# Select a string inside an element jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, element

```
<li>
    <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Link</a>
    "That was a link"
</li>
```

How would you, with jQuery, select the "That was a link" string? Obviously using **$('li:last')** won't work, as **:last** has to select an element.

So how do you? Let's just say I need to remove it with **.remove()**

Comment: Can you put a `<span>` around the text?

Comment: Nope, that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$($('li')[0].lastChild).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/djJQu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a few ways. Here's one solution that may not be perfect, but should work:

```
 <li>
 <a id="myID" href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Link</a>
"That was a link"
 </li>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#myID').text();

</script>
```

You could also change the text of the list item by using this:

```
$('#myID').text('your text here');
```

The remove() function is not what you want here. That is used to remove an entire element, not just text.

Comment: You do realise that it's the string I am talking about, right? Not the a-tag text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method

```
('li').contents().last().remove()
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/QJW4N/

---

**Quote**

> **Description**: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.